# Query Importrange with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am trying to query ImportRange data by 2 conditions.

First I need that a column matches a value from the imported spreadsheet. 
Then, I need to get only the columns that have any data.

I am having trouble with the second step.

I am getting the data i want with:

```
=Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets...";"Answers to forms!A1:DB1100");"select * where Col8='Fem'")
```

But, when I do this there are a lot of empty columns that I want to leave out of the query.

I've already tried some expressions or conditionals but all of them showed an error and I don't really know the syntax needed here.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What did you try and what errors were you getting?